# Site does not work right, pages not showing up, even for root admin

Tags: database, troubleshooting

I have a problem. My database server isn't working right. On a wiki, it gives an error, and on my wordpress site, the pages don't show up. I am wondering if WordPress caches the DB data in any way, and if so, how do I clear it. I am hoping that will either totally break it or clear it. I am able to disable plugins and change settings, just the pages don't show up.

**Edit:** The only thing I can't access is the pages. Everything else is working OK, I think. Also, this just cropped up in the last couple of days. Before that, it was fine. I just noticed it today.

**Edit 2:** I mean pages as in posts and pages, not webpages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your input. This may help someone else who has this problem. As for me, the problem has fixed itself (well, not exactly, but it is gone), so it must have been the DB. The wiki is still down, but it says that a table is marked as crashed now.

Comment: It was the database. I have now switched from MediaWiki to a file-based tiddlywiki on this particular site because of continuous database problems. WordPress doesn't have as many problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to confirm that the wp-config.php is well configured, but if you can't access your backend with root access **I'd check file and folder permissions**. Usually you should have 644 permissions on almost every subfolder inside your wordpress installation, though there are others (such as wp-content/uploads) that should be writeable too.

Comment: I can access the backend, it is just that some of the stuff is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try resetting the permalinks in Settings > Permalinks. But if this is also happening in a separate wiki that has nothing to do with WordPress except share a database, it might not have anything to do with WordPress at all... Wish I could be of more help! A link to your site might help with more troubleshooting.